# Conditional Statements (IF, Else) not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to apply some if else statements in my code but getting a bit confused. I want a result if I got value=0 answer should be One. if I got value=1 answer should be Two and if I got any value greater then 1 value should be Three. Following is my code: -

```
$value = 1
if($value < 1)
{
  echo "One";
}
else if($value === '1')
{
  echo "Two";
}
else if($value >= 2)
{
  echo "Three";
}
```

The problem is that it is not giving me results if value is = 1.

Comment: `1 == '1'`, but `1 !== '1'` (they are of different types). See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `=== '1'` does not equal to `=== 1` so just change  it if your `$value` is integer

Comment: `$value = 1` < did you even close it off? It's missing a semi-colon here.

Answer (score 1):

change this `else if($value === '1')` to `else if($value == 1)`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

`===` matched both value and type that's why `1==='1'` is **false**, See [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

`$a === $b`     Identical **TRUE** if $a is **equal** to $b, and they are of the **same** type.

```
<?php
$value = 1;
if($value < 1)
{
    echo "One";
}
else if($value == '1')
{
    echo "Two";
}
else if($value >= 2)
{
    echo "Three";
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/avOWc